# How to send parameters to backend, and get response message, using GET method in volley, android?

Tags: android, get, android-volley

I want to send three parameters "guestEmail", "latitude" and "longitude" to backend and get a message of success from backend if it is successful.

I have tried doing this:

```
public void myGetFunc()
{

final String url = "....";

// prepare the Request
JsonObjectRequest getRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {   
                        // display response     
            Log.d("Response", response.toString());
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }, 
    new Response.ErrorListener() 
    {
         @Override
         public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {            
            Log.d("Error.Response", response);
       }
    }
)

{

    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() 
    {  
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String> ();  
            params.put("guestEmail", "abc@xyz.com");  
            params.put("latitude", "12");
            params.put("longitude", "12");

            return params;  
    }
};

// add it to the RequestQueue   
queue.add(getRequest);
}
```

This method is invoked when the 'SOS' button is clicked.
But right now, nothing happens on clicking the 'SOS' button.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use GET you query parameters and build the string yourself

```
private static final String URL = "http://www.test.com?value1={val1}&value2={val2}";

String requestString = URL;
requestString.replace("{val1}", "1");
requestString.replace("{val2}", "Bob");

StringRequest strreq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
     requestString,
      new Response.Listener<String>() {
         @Override
         public void onResponse(String Response) {
                  // get response
         }
      }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
         @Override
         public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
});
Volley.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(strreq);
```

If you are going to use POST us a body

```
public class LoginRequest extends Request<String> {

    // ... other methods go here

    private Map<String, String> mParams;

    public LoginRequest(String param1, String param2, Listener<String> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(Method.POST, "http://test.url", errorListener);
        mListener = listener;
        mParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
        mParams.put("paramOne", param1);
        mParams.put("paramTwo", param2);

    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return mParams;
    }
}
```

Comment: Zachary Sweigart, do we get response from the server in onResponse method ?
I'm not getting it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass parameters than you need to use POST method otherwise for GET , just pass values in URL itself.

Comment: Can you tell me how to pass it in URL? Example?

Comment: you can pass like this. for ex - www.yoursite.com?myparam1={id1}&myparam2={id2}...in your case www.yoursite.com?guestEmail=abc@xyz.com&latitude=12&longitude=12

Comment: Bro, just a quick question. I have the email stored in a string 
"guestEmail", latitude in "strLat" and longitude is "strLng".
Should the URL be: "www.yoursite.com?guestEmail=guestEmail&latitude=strLat&longitude=strLng" 
I'm getting error using this. Not sure if it's error of URL format or something else.